# Need to link pages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im a newbie in laravel. I went though the route documentation on the Laravel site. Thing I want to create a new tab in my menu, I have added the tab but cannot seem to link it. When i Read on the laravels site, it said you need to edit routes.php file, and so I did, but it didnt seem to work. Im sure im missing something out. Could you please help me?
The website is on jfgfestival.com I want to add the tab after Press.

Im running Laravel 4.1

This is what I have added to routes.php

```
Route::get('videos', function()
{
    $featured_images = Featured::get();
    $categories = Category::get();
    return View::make('home.videos')->with(compact('featured_videos', 'categories'));
});
```

Also this new page that Im creating is for a video gallery. Does any one know how to create a video gallery in laravel? I cannot seem to find any good references/ tutorials for the same.

Thank you again

Comment: 1) Laravel is a framework, not a CMS, there can't be a "build a video gallery" section, you need to make it by coding; 2) by going to your route, I get error "view home.videos not found", looks like you didn't create the view file, or you put it in the wrong folder

Comment: Thank you for correcting me with regards to the cms part. This is my first time with a framework so dont know much about it. What i meant was that if anyone could point me to a site or video tut or a ready script, that could help me make a video gallery, that would be helpful..because when i type it in google, i just get it for image gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the view file you specified set up.  For this route it should be in:

```
app/views/home/videos.blade.php
```